# Search message api with from:botname does not seem to work

Tags: slack-api

Using the [tester](https://api.slack.com/methods/search.messages/test) provided on api.slack.com, I am trying to search for messages from a particular bot that I have created and install. The documentation state that I could use `from:botname` in the `query` parameter, which I did, but it return zero result.

Searching for messages from a user with `from:@User` works and if I use `in:channel` to search for all messages from a channel, I can see the messages posted by the bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't really understood how it works, but if you provide an alternative username other than the name of the app when posting a new message, you will be able to search with `from:username`.